# Having difficulty with javascript(node.js) that needs to be synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, synchronous

I have an express.js app that needs to run a script on the server in order to derive some values using functions later. Here's the gist of it:

```
shell.exec(commandString);

readFolder();

renderPage();
```

Essentially, I need to run a script on the server, then run the second function, then run the third function. These need to happen subsequently, but it seems that javascript moves on ahead with the the second and third function no matter what I do. I've tried promises, async, callbacks. All of which I only partially understand and seem to get zero progress.

I will admit that I am a javascript novice. I am working on a project with others and this task fell to me. I doubt this is the best way to accomplish our ultimate goals, but I am left with little choice. please help.

I'll put the entire post here for reference:

```
//Run script when post is rec'd from root and send to results page
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
var commandString;

//take values and create complete command for Astrum script
commandString = 'bash /home/astrum/Main/Astrum.sh -s ' + req.body.speed + ' -h ' + req.body.host + ' -u ' + req.body.username + ' -p ' + req.body.password;

//execute command in shell
shell.exec(commandString);

readFolder();

renderPage();


//Iterate thru filenames to create arrays for links and link labels
function readFolder() {

    fs.readdir('./reports/html/', (err, files) => {
            
        //variable & method for links to html records pages
        ipAddressesLink = files; //this is initialized earlier, globally
        
        //variable and method to remove file extension for link labels in pug
        ipAddresses = files.map(removeExtension); //this is initialized earlier, globally
   
    });

}

//function to remove last five characters of each element
function removeExtension(value) {

    return value.substring(0, value.length - 5);

};

//function to render the page
function renderPage() {

    res.render("results", {ipAddressesLink, ipAddresses, title: 'Results'});

}

res.end();
```

});

Comment: shell is from the shell.js npm module

Answer (score 0):

Is shell here the `child_process` module? If it is then you can pass an optional callback argument and call your functions from there.

```html
shell.exec(commandString, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  const files = readFolder();
  renderPage(files);
});

function readFolder() {
  ...
  return fs.readdirSync(files);
}

function renderPage(files) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: shell is from the shell.js module

Comment: From the documentation, the exec function is synchronous by default although the callback method still works. Do the readFolder or renderPage functions perform asynchronous actions?

Comment: My understanding was most things are asynchronous by default; readFolder() uses the fs.readdir(files) method to define some arrays initialized globally earlier.

renderPage() sends those arrays to the view engine (pug) as part of the res.render method to be used as links and labels, created by a for each loop in pug.

The problem I am encountering with my original code is that the arrays are undefined when they are sent to the view engine, but ARE defined if I try a second time; meaning something is getting skipped the first time.

Comment: Yeah, all methods on fs are async by default node provides a synchronous version something like fs.readdirSync(file). You could switch your current implementation to use the sync methods or properly handle the async with promises or callbacks. Editing the answer to reflect an implementation for readFolder

Answer (score 0):

You could write it this way:

```
shell.exec(commandString, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  // Calling the 1st function after shell command is executed
  readFolder();
});

function readFolder() {
  fs.readdir('./reports/html/', (err, files) => {
    // Some stuff
    ...
    // Calls the 2nd function after fs is done reading files
    renderPage();
  });
}

function renderPage() {
  const options = { ... }; // IP addresses etc.
  res.render(
    "results",
    options,
    // Calls the final function after render is finished
    sendResponse
  );
}

function sendResponse(err, html) {
   // Sends the response. It’s possible that res.send() is the better solution here
   res.end();
}
```

It’s just the general structure of the callback chain, definitely not the cleanest one. If you want better code structure and readability try switching to [async / await](https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await) syntax.